# Remove unused CSS rules in Chrome Audit

Tags: magento-2.1, chrome-browser

I am auditing `magento 2` website performance using Chrome Audits. It warns to `Remove unused CSS rules`. Is it possible to fix that warning.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can clean up the unused CSS using [grunt-uncss](https://github.com/addyosmani/grunt-uncss) plugin